# Client form submit datetime, MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC application with a number of forms. When the form is submitted it passed the users gps coordinates to the server. I also want to pass the clients current datetime.

Does anyone have any ideas as to the best way to do this?

The forms are standard html forms and use a basic submit.

My form would look like the one below. So how would I best attach the javascript datetime value to the submit call?

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CheckIn", "Home", "Nothing", new AjaxOptions { }))
            {
                <fieldset>
                    <p>Move your Tile here to let those around you see it...</p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="hckLat" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="lon" id="hckLon" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="date" id="hckDate" value="" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Check In!" />
                </fieldset>
            }
```

Comment: What part is not clear? How to create a date in JavaScript? How to assign it's value to a form input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `JavaScript` and the `Date` function which is rendered on the clients machine.

```
var d = new Date();
```

Then you could pass the variable d to the server when you submit the co-ordinates.

From your edit:

In your `Checkin` method in the`Home controller`, you could specify:

```
public ActionResult Checkin(string hckLat, string hckLong, string hckDate) 
{
    var theDate = hckDate;
}
```

To set the value of `hckDate`, you could do:

On the submit button click:

```
<input type="button" name="theSubmitButton" id="theSubmitButton" value="Button"   onClick="setDate();">

function setDate() {
   var e = document.getElementById('hckDate');

   e.value = new Date();
}
```

This would then be sent to the server.

Comment: @BenCameron In your question you state "the form is submitted it passed the users gps coordinates to the server" - when you submit the co-ordinates, just specify the variable d too and it will get sent to the server.  Understand?

Comment: Not really. I have added th form to the question. So how would I attach the datetime value to the form?

Comment: @BenCameron - Does your "Checkin" function in the Home controller have model binding properties "hckLat", "hckLong", you could just modify the controller to take "hckDate"

Comment: Yes it does take a param named that. The problem is how do I set that value on the form when the users clicks the submit button?

Comment: That does help but how do i set hckDate in the form to be the time the user clicks the button?

Comment: @BenCameron I've outlined how you can capture the button click and set the value of hckDate

Comment: Works a treat. Very simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use the javascript function:

```
var currentDateTime = new Date()
```

then maybe look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format it for the mvc controller